# android file.exists() doesn't work until app is reopened

Tags: android, root

I am building an android app that makes it easy to view previously saved Wifi ssids. The problem I face is I use RootTools library to issue bash commands as root to copy the system file to the sdcard.

My app cannot open the file until I have restated the app. It almost seems like it needs the index of files on the sdcard to be refreshed. After I close out of the app, and open it, file.exists() works as it should and comes back true.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Thanks, Derek.

Comment: You can force the system to rescan the file

Comment: Don't save passwords your contributing to delinquency and apps that are not secure.  Wifi passwords are already saved in the cloud.  Remove the word password from your question.

Answer (score 0):

run this method after you create the file
of course you need READ/WRITE permissions in the android manifest

```
 public void refreshMedia(Context context,File file) {
            MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context, new String[] { file.getAbsolutePath() }, null, new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                    // now file.exists() will return true
            }       
        });
    }
```

Comment: That's the strange thing. I can run that and call file.exists() after but it still doesn't find the file until I close the app and reopen. I'm on 5.0.1 I may try it on 4.4 to see if its something they changed with 5.0.